# Django CreateView - only allow n number of objects created. Redirect if limit is reached

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

thanks for taking the time to read this.

I am making a simple CRM app with Django. This is my model.

**models.py**

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    contact_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is my view that allows user to create contacts.

**views.py**

```py
class CreateContact(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'network/contacts_list.html'
    form_class = ContactForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.contact_owner = self.request.user
        return super(CreateContact, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateContact, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contacts'] = Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=self.request.user)
        return context
```

I am trying restrict amount of contacts a user can create. I have looked into a few ways of achieving this before writing this question.

1. Using RedirectView. It only seems to work for GET requests. As far as I understand in my question situation, POST request is submitted. So this does not work.
2. Using form_invalid. I thought that I could use this function to redirect me to a page if the request failed. I couldn't figure out how to pass a url in the form_invalid function. I don't think that's what it is for.

Essentially, I think I need to add a count statement somewhere in the CreateView query and if it is larger than 200, then reverse('somewhere-else'). I can't figure out how to do that within CreateView, and I am super unfamiliar with Function Based Views.

Thanks a ton for taking the time to read this. I really value your time.

If you have any questions or need any further context, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the **`post(...)`** method of CBV,

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


class CreateContact(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # other code

    def is_limit_reached(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=self.request.user).count() >= 100

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_limit_reached():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('somewhere-else'))
        else:
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I know we are not supposed to be saying thanks and things like that in the comments, but this is what I am going to day. This is so clean and so simple, and will help me in my future projects. I am very thankful for your help! 
To anyone reading this in the future, code above works perfectly.

Comment: I was searching for a similar solution. Performing an arbitrary redirect isn't the most user-friendly way to do this in my opinion. You would be better off using `UserPassesTestMixin`, putting your test logic in the `test_func` method and raising a `PermissionDenied` error with an exception value like you would any other exception.